# Getting JSON response with PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to connect an API that uses 0AUTH2 via PHP. The original plan was to use client-side JS, but that isn't possible with 0AUTH2.

I'm simply trying get a share count from the API's endpoint which is here:
https://api.bufferapp.com/1/links/shares.json?url=[your-url-here]&access_token=[your-access-key-here]

I do have a proper access_token that I am using to access the json file, that is working fine.

This is the code I have currently written, but I'm not even sure I'm on the right track.

```
// 0AUTH2 ACCESS TOKEN FOR AUTHENTICATION
$key = '[my-access-key-here]';

// JSON URL TO BE REQUESTED
$json_url = 'https://api.bufferapp.com/1/links/shares.json?url=http://bufferapp.com&access_token=' . $key;

// GET THE SHARE COUNT FROM THE REQUEST
$json_string = '[shares]';

// INITIALIZE CURL
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );


// CONFIG CURL OPTIONS
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $json_string
);

// SETTING CURL AOPTIONS
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// GET THE RESULTS
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
```

Like I said, I don't know if this is the best method - so I'm open to any suggestions. 
I'm just trying to retrieve the share count with this PHP script, then with JS, spit out the share count where I need it on the page.

Comment: What's your question? What's not working?

Comment: Currently I cannot seem to get a response.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: It is my understanding that curl_exec($ch); returns true or false; So I have set up an ajax call to tell me whether the response is true or false. This is my testing environment. http://blog.onestepcreative.com/environments/share/

Comment: There's still no specific question here. If you're looking for debugging help, this is not the place for it (without being much more specific). If you're looking for code review, check out [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @orourkek sorry for not being more clear. I have since posted an answer to my question. Sorry for wasting your time, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for wasting anyone's time. I have since been able to work this out. All the code is essentially the same - to test to see if you're getting the correct response, just print it to the page. Again, sorry to have wasted anyones time.

```
<?php

// 0AUTH2 ACCESS TOKEN FOR AUTHENTICATION
$key    = '[your_access_key_here]';

// URL TO RETRIEVE SHARE COUNT FROM
$url = '[your_url_here]';

// JSON URL TO BE REQUESTED - API ENDPOINT
$json_url = 'https://api.bufferapp.com/1/links/shares.json?url=' . $url . ' &access_token=' . $key;

// GET THE SHARE COUNT FROM THE REQUEST
$json_string = '[shares]';

// INITIALIZE CURL
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// CONFIG CURL OPTIONS
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $json_string
);

// SETTING CURL AOPTIONS
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// GET THE RESULTS
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

print $result;


?>
```